# ¿Cómo ejecutar un script Python usando PHP en window?

Tags: php, python, codeigniter

Quiero ejecutar un script hecho en Python con PHP lo que hecho es lo siguiente

**codigo php**

```
<?php 
$output = array();
echo "hola ps ";

exec("python holamundo.py",$output);

echo $output[0]; 
 ?>
```

**codigo python**

```
import msvcrt 
print("HOLA MUNDO; Soy Python me han llamado desde PHP");
msvcrt.getch()
```

Esta es la estructura del directorio donde están estos archivos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La forma que ejecuto el PHP es dando su URL.

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad alguna de las respuestas?

Answer (score 1):

Para ejecutarlo debes utilizar PHP: exec
http://php.net/manual/es/function.exec.php

Y tener el interprete de python en la Terminal (hablando de Linux) o la linea de Comandos de windows.

Asi podras hacer algo como

```
<?php
exec('C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\Username\Desktop\my_python_script.py')
```

Puede que no funcione por que windows es muy latoso con eso. En el caso de que manejes Linux, o Mac

```
<?php
exec('python my_python_script.py')
```

Comment: ¿Y no requiere ningún permiso? Pregunto por si alguno lo intenta en un servidor  de paga como en godady o webhost

Answer (score 0):

Para ejecutar ***php***, desde linea de comando, si no lo tienes incluido en el ***path***. Solo tienes que entrar en una consola  ***cmd*** en el caso de ***windows*** y colocarte dentro del directorio php y ejecutarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
php -f nombre_del_script.php
```

Para ejecutar programas externos desde php, lo puedes hacer tanto ***exec*** o ***system***. El ***exec*** ya lo estas usando en tu script. Ambos comando te devuelven un string, esto quiere decir que si imprimes algún contenido el programa externo lo puedes utilizar en tu código ***php***. El script que contenga estos programas lo mismo lo puedas ejecutar desde linea de comando o a través de un ***URL***. Te dejo el ejemplo:

```
echo exec('hola.exe');
```

Comment: gracias, pero yo quiero ejecutar el escript de python usando php

Comment: es de esta forma, pero tu PHP debe decir py no python